# Flex TileList itemrenderer + scroll = HELL

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, tilelist

I'm going insane over this issue. Basically, I have a TileList with a custom item renderer that has a TextInput in it. Let's say that the list can show 4 items at once, if there are 5 items and I edit the text on the first one, the fifth will be edited also. In general if an item is out of view, it will be change when I edit one that is showing.

Also, I had overriden the TileList class to expose the rendererArray property (so that I could access the texts on each renderer) but it will only return the renderers which are displayed.

Any help is appreciated. I need to know how to override this weird behaviour with itemrenderers that aren't currently displayed. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, are you sure that the data objects in the dataProvider are not cross-linked somehow?

Comment: I don't think they are, I went as far as creating them manually and setting different properties for each one. I suspect it has something to do with reuse.

Comment: If I make the component long enough to show all 5 items, the problem goes away. Is there a way to force the TileList to create all its renderers at once and not reuse them?

Comment: Thanks flextras, your comment rang a bell. I created a new custom object that would hold the properties of the TextInput and a checkbox. I used this object as the "data" for the itemrenderer and used the "change" event to update the data property when the TextInput text was changed. This way I could iterate through the data provider instead of the itemrenderers themselves and all is well now :)

Comment: @JayPea, if you're not going to answer your own question or give us more information on your question so we can answer it, you can just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if anyone runs into a similar issue, here is what you need to do:

First of all, avoid trying to iterate through the itemrenderers like I did. If you need a TextInput or another control on your TileList, make sure that these controls are bound to a property on your data object, otherwise off-screen items will have incorrect values since their itemrenderers will be recycled from the items that left the screen when you scrolled.

If you think it through, any requirement can be solved by iterating through the dataprovider instead of the itemrenderers.

Also, if you try to expose the rendererArray property like I did, notice that you will only be able to iterate through the itemrenderers that are currently displayed, since those that would belong to the items that are off-screen will not be created yet.

I hope this wasn't too confusing..